# "\\1" vs. $1. Why am i getting different results in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I am using this in a longer script but a short example will illustrate the type of problem I have.

```
my_array2 = ["help", "not", "too"]
my_array2.each do |element|
  element.sub!(/(\w{1})(\w+)/,"\\1")
end

# this gives me the expected ['h','n','t']
```

If instead I do

```
my_array2 = ["help", "not", "too"]
my_array2.each do |element| 
  element.sub!(/(\w{1})(\w+)/, $1)
end

# this gives me ['t','h','n'] (instead of ['h','n','t'] as expected).
```

What is going on?  Why am I getting a 'shifted' result when I use `$1` to return the first regex capture group?

Comment: You have to use the block form, i.e. `sub!(/.../) { $1 }`. Otherwise, $1 refers to the previous match.

Comment: The indirect answer is: Variables are passed by value in Ruby. The value of `$1` *before your `sub!` call* is what is being passed into `sub!`, not a reference to `$1` which will eventually be populated inside the `sub!` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$1` is a reference to the match of the first group from the last regex match. It's value is evaluated at the time of passing it to the method (`String#sub!`) and not after the matching is done.

Therefore, the `t` comes from your previous experiment with `\1`. If you open a fresh repl and run your second example, you will get `TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String`. This is because `$1` is `nil` at the time you call the first `String#sub!`.

Comment: Wouldn't that return ['nil', 'h', 'n']?  Why would the last element's match end up first?

Comment: @RicmanR, for the first question - because `String#sub` is defined to raise an error if the replacee is `nil`. Try `''.sub('', nil)` in irb. For the second question - the `t` in the first position of your second code sample is leftover from the `"too".gsub...` from the first code sample. The `h` is leftover from the first match in the second code sample. The `n` is leftover from the second match in the second code sample.

Comment: Oops, just saw the remainder of your post.  Thanks!